# Find the slope of the line that goes through the given points

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the formula for this type of problem is the second y coordinate subtracted from the first y coordinate over the second x coordinate subtracted from the first x coordinate but for the numbers given to me for this problem (-9, - 5) and (-7, 5) it says the slope = 5 I am getting 10 over 16. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is 10 over 2.

Comment: Yes: $-7-(-9)=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you aren't subtracting in the denominator.

As you said, the slope of the line passing through $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2})$ is $\dfrac{y_{2} - y_{1}}{x_{2} - x_{1}}$.

You have the points $(-9, -5)$ and $(-7,5)$.

You have been calculating this as $\dfrac{-5 - 5}{-9 + -7} = \dfrac{-10}{-16}$.  Notice that you did $x_{2} + x_{1}$ in the denominator, not $x_{2} - x_{1}$.

The correct answer is $\dfrac{-5 - 5}{-9 - (-7)} = \dfrac{-10}{-9 + 7} = \dfrac{-10}{-2} = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

You have:
$$
m= \dfrac{5-(-5)}{-7-(-9)}=\dfrac{10}{2} =5
$$